# Is "head of the heads" right?

Tags: word-choice

I want to say I am the Head of The Heads of all Scientific Councils of the University, elected democratically by heads of all student scientific councils to act as their delegate.

Is the head of heads OK? or It's better to say In charge of the heads...
the points is it is a title of a position, that is the head of heads is elected by other heads.
it sounds kind of unnatural to me.

Comment: There are other words you could use, like _director, dean, chief,_ or _president_. The best choice of words depends on the amount of authority and leadership you have while in that position, as well as whether it's a permanent position, or one where someone new gets elected on a regular basis. To be truthful, I would ask others in the council what they think would be a good name for the position.

Comment: @J.R.it is not a permanent position. the person should act as the speaker and delegate of them, give speeches as a representative, discuss the issued with university authorities

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest one of the following:

> Delegate of the Scientific Councils
>   Lead Delegate of the Scientific Councils

I'd wait for others to weigh in, though, since I don't have experience with these types of organizations, and there may be a more standard term to use.

Comment: Thanks. Is "Lead Delegate of The Student Scientific Councils of Allameh University" OK?

Comment: @user43947 Sounds like an impressive title to me. :-)

Comment: @user43947 By the way, the word "the" would not normally be capitalized.

Comment: The "the" could also be omitted: _Lead Delegate of Student Scientfic Councils_. I'd also recommend **against** putting the name of the school in the duty title itself; a job title is usually named so that the same title could be used at multiple institutions.